# How can I change cache control on actuator routes?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-java-config, spring-boot-actuator

Since you don't tend to write Actuator controllers, they've been written for you, how would you add, for example `cache-control: nocache` to `/health`?

Answer (score 2):

See the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-health-access-restrictions):

> ...the response is cached for a configurable period to prevent the endpoint being used in a denial of service attack. The `endpoints.health.time-to-live` property is used to configure the caching period in milliseconds. It **defaults to 1000**, i.e. one second.

This is available only for */health* endpoint, though, other actuator endpoints don't seem to have this property.